# How to get Management API Access Token to use on Auth0 /api/v2/users endpoint

Tags: swift, auth0

So I'm making a request to the Auth0 `/api/v2/users` endpoint to receive user info. I was using `Management API Access Tokens` for testing at first which was just copy and pasting in the access token in my `/api/v2/users` request. But now I'm trying to get the `Management API Access Tokens` for my `/api/v2/users` endpoint for production. Do I need a `backend` for this or can I get the `Management API Access Tokens` on my `front end` only? Can someone bullet point the steps I have to take in order to get the `Management API Access Token` for production purposes?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a backend to get a Management API Access Token for production purposes.

From their Applications documentation - https://auth0.com/docs/applications:

> Protect your client secrets and never include them in mobile or browser-based apps. If your client secret is ever compromised, you should rotate to a new one and update all authorized apps with the new client secret.

For the steps to do that, you can find them here:
https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/management-api-access-tokens/get-management-api-access-tokens-for-production